# How to set yaw offset in robot_pose_ekf/robot_localization?

Tags: navigation, move-base, robot-localization, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am planning to use odmetry x,y, yaw as well as imu yaw data in robot_pose_ekf package. Since the imu will start at some yaw value relative to magnetic north? Do I have to programatically set that yaw value as 0 and pass the relative yaw to robot_pose_ekf or will it set the yaw offset itself. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255044/how-to-set-yaw-offset-in-robot_pose_ekf/robot_localization?/) by [bigboateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/28511/bigboateng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2017-02-21**:
Is this question for `robot_pose_ekf` of `robot_localization`?

**Comment by [bigboateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/28511/bigboateng/) on 2017-02-21**:
Hi, I I'm trying both packages and I think I'm going to use robot_pose_ekf instead as it just takes in euler angles as input for imu. But I i think you should be able to tell the package that when the program starts, assume its current yaw is 0 degrees/rads so every reading is relative to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For robot_localization, you can set the IMU to `relative` mode if you want to to start at 0.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2017-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0